# Creating 'form' in html not working . .

Tags: html, forms

I wrote the following code to create a form. But it's not working. The output only has 'Please enter any feedback you have' and 'Please enter your text here' as texts without any form.  I'm just not able to find any bug here. Please help.
Also, the code works fine in my friend's computer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My webpage</title>
    <meta name='author' content='Sparsh'>


</head>
<body>


<form action="forhtml.txt" method="post"> 
  <p>Please enter any feedback you have.</p>  
 <textarea rows="3" cols="60" name="feedback">  
 Please enter your text here   
 </textarea>  
 <br>   
 <input type="submit" value="Send"> 
 </form> 
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Works fine for me as well. There’s something else going wrong. Unfortunately, there’s no way for us to tell what it is.

Comment: `<form action="forhtml.txt"` that will never work. It needs to be a `.php` file.

Comment: There's also no "php" to support the question since this should really be php-related.

Comment: I don't know yet how to create a php file.

Answer (score 0):

The form is loading properly although are you referring to it not saving the text properly to the text file you specified?

You cannot post directly to a text file in that fashion as far as I am aware of.  You can however try the following:

Form

```
<form action="processing.html" method="post"> 
  <p>Please enter any feedback you have.</p>  
 <textarea rows="3" cols="60" name="feedback">  
 Please enter your text here   
 </textarea>  
 <br>   
 <input type="submit" value="Send"> 
 </form>
```

processing.html (Code is javascript)

```
$myFile = "forhtml.txt";
if(isset($_POST['feedback']) && !empty($_POST['feedback'])) {
      $feedback = $_POST['feedback'];
}
if($feedback) {
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, $feedback);
    fclose($fh);
}
```

This is untested but should work as expected.

Comment: No, the form is not loading at all. Only texts are displayed.

Comment: All I can do is test the piece you gave above and it works fine as seen at http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FAM8DJTETA8G ... hit run and it will load to the right.

Comment: And now the code I posted, which was not working since 2 days, works. I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: But there is still this problem of the content of form not being saved in the 'processing.html' file.

Comment: Can you post an error you are getting here or the URL of the page that you have the code on so I can take a look?